# Client-side generated document sequences with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, architecture

We want to build a Node.js API that stores schema-less documents in a MongoDB collection. Every document should have a key "no" which orders them in a sequence:

```
[
   { "no": 1, ... }, 
   { "no": 2, ... }, 
   { "no": 3, ... }, 
   { "no": 4, ... }, 
   ...
]
```

We have the following constraints:

- The sequencing, including other parameters, need to be cryptographically signed. Therefore, the server cannot set a sequence number that the client does not know before signing and sending the data.
- `no` must be unique (Not allowed: 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3)
- There must not be any gaps in the sequencing (Not allowed: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5)
- The API is replicated, so there will be a lot of concurrent requests against MongoDB.
- The API client is not not a browser application, it actually is a Node.js application as well. There will be **only one API client**

Our starting point is to have an API that on every storage request returns the next sequence number.

```
POST /collection { "no": 1, ...}
returns {"next": 2}
```

Will this work?

On the client side, it could be something like this pseudo code:

```
let next

module.exports.create = (document, cb) => {
   if (!next) next = 1 // here it is probably better to sync the initial no with the db instead always starting with 1
   document.no = next
   return post('/collection', document, (err, res) => {
       if (err) ...
       next = res.next
       return cb(...)
   }
}
```

If `create` on the client side is called by many concurrent callers, can there be a case where two or more create requests have duplicate `no`'s?

Comment: Your scheme of returning the next sequence number is not safe from race conditions if there are ever multiple clients.  Usually, the client just asks to add a new document to the end of the list and the server assigns the next sequence number in a way that is safe from race conditions (only the server can do this in a safe way).

Comment: Adding a few words in bold does not change the fact that this is not safe. If the intention is storage on the server, then the sequencing should come from there. We could tell you to create a local storage DB for keeping sequence but the use case here is still very unclear. Is you insistence on the "client" responsibility possibly related to "re-ordering the list"? if so then there may be alternatives.  Bottom line is this is presently both unclear and broad because you are focusing too much on justifying your case instead presenting the actual problem to solve.

Comment: And when you are unlcear and broad, you get answers like the one you just got. So it's better just to describe the use case and ask "how to solve it" instead.

Comment: I've updated the post. The sequence, amongst other inputs, will be cryptographically signed. Therefore, the sequence number needs to be known to the client before saving it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When you have concurrent API calls and the client has the right to determine the sequencing, it's pretty much impossible for you to achieve what you're trying to if the client has the full rights to determining the sequence.

However, if the *sequence no* cannot have any gap in between and it must be sequential, why must the client be the one providing the *sequence no*? You could have easily agreed on a sequencing pattern (e.g. 1,2,3,4 or AB1, AB2, AB3, etc) and let the server side do the inserting of *sequence no* depending on which request comes in first. Make a collection that generates running number using `findAndModify` and let server update the sequence no into the database instead.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post. The client needs to know the sequence number before hand because it (and not just the sequence number) will be signed by the client.

Comment: Assuming that you have a mean to determine that the sequence no is sequential, you may have a collection with a single row to keep track of your last valid sequence no, again, using `findAndModify`. If the client calls you API and provides an invalid sequence no, throw HTTP status `400`. If they provide you with a valid one, proceed with the insertion. Note that `findAndModify` will not work with sharded collections, iirc